# HTTP Error 404: Not Found - BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a script to scrape a site but I keep getting an "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found".  I have tried adding the user agent to the header and running the script and I still get the same error.  Here is my code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import json

atd_url = 'https://courses.lumenlearning.com/catalog/achievingthedream'

#opening up connection and grabbing page
res = Request(atd_url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'})
uClient = urlopen(res)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs info for each textbook
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"book-info"})

data = []
for container in containers:
   item = {}
   item['type'] = "Course"
   item['title'] = container.h2.text
   item['author'] = container.p.text
   item['link'] = container.p.a["href"]
   item['source'] = "Achieving the Dream Courses"
   item['base_url'] = "https://courses.lumenlearning.com/catalog/achievingthedream"
   data.append(item) # add the item to the list

with open("./json/atd-lumen.json", "w") as writeJSON:
   json.dump(data, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Here is the full error message I get every time I run the script

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "atd-lumen.py", line 9, in <module>
uClient = urlopen(res)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?  It is a valid link when entered into a browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use requests library instead, this works:

```
import requests

#opening up connection and grabbing page
response = requests.get(atd_url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'})

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(response.content, "html.parser")
```